# Laravel Page Error - Printing 1 on top of every page

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 with having normal views and controller.

in my web.php I have following routes:

```
Route::get('/quiz', 'QuizController@quiz');
Route::post('quiz/submit', array('uses' => 'QuizController@check'));
```

Everything was working fine as I started writing **Check()** function

```
public function check(Request $request)
    {  

        $answers = array_flatten($request->except('_token'));
        $quiz =  config('enums.quiz');
        $correct = [];
        $result = [];
        foreach ($quiz as $key => $value) {
             foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                 if ($val == 1) {
                    array_push($correct,  $key );
                 }
             }
        }
        foreach ($answers as $key => $value) {
            if ($correct[$key] == $value ) {
                $result[$value] = 1;
            }else {
                $result[$value] = 0;
            }
        }
        $request->session()->flash('results', $result);
        redirect('/quiz');
    }
```

and quiz.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Quiz
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">


        {!!  Form::open(array('id'=> 'updateForm', 'style'=>'margin-bottom:10px;' ,"class"=>"form-horizontal" , "ng-app"=>"userform",   'url' => array('quiz/submit'))) !!}
        <ol type="1">
            @foreach ($questions as $question => $answers)
            {{-- loop throgh each question --}}
            <li class="question">
                <h4>
                    <strong>
                        {{ $question }}
                    </strong>
                </h4>
                <ol type="a">
                    @foreach ($answers as $answer => $isCorrect)
                    {{-- looping answers  of the question --}}                       

                    <li class="answer ">
                        <input name="answer_{{ $loop->parent->index }}" required="" type="radio"  value="{{ $answer }}">
                        {{ $answer }}
                    </input>
                </li>
                @endforeach
            </ol>
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ol>

    <button class="btn btn-ok btn-default text-uppercase pull-right">Clear Answers</button>
    <span style="margin: 5px;" class="pull-right"> </span>
    {!! Form::submit('Submit Quiz', array('id'=>'btn_submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-ok btn-primary text-uppercase pull-right ' )) !!} 
    {!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And then suddenly It starts printing **1** on top of every page. even I tried to clear compile and clear session but still if creating a problem.

```
php artisan clear-compiled
1The compiled services file has been removed.
```

the same 1 is being printed on top of each page, hence stop requests of login or any other page request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's printing `1`, it's not a `dd()` statement, it's an `echo` statement. Likely a `{{ $var }}` echo in a blade layout (like @Benjamin King said)`, or it's an `echo $var` somewhere in your code. If it prints before any HTML does (inspect the source) then that's more than likely the case.

Comment: I saw it everywhere 
it is also coming on all of PHP artisan commands
it seems like some issue with laravel cache or something but I am unable to see any solution

Comment: It's not an issue with Laravel cache, you've got something somewhere.

Comment: in order to debug i tried to  add
Route::get('/', function () {
 die();
 return view('welcome');
});


but still 1 is there, couldn't figure out why

Comment: That's because it happens way before it gets to the Route file. Put some broken code in there and refresh the page. An error will be thrown with a stack trace. Walk through all of the files that appear in that trace until you find the file that has the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you `config` folder php files. There shoulb be `1` before `<?php` one of the php files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting "1" displayed at the top of every page... That is, including at the top of pages not returned by '/quiz', and the "1" is displaying above the Bootstrap panel in your 'content' section from quiz.blade.php... Then my first guess is that you inadvertently changed something in your layouts.app blade file. Check there. Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw it everywhere 
it is also coming on all of PHP artisan commands
it seems like some issue with laravel cache or something but I am unable to see any solution

Comment: The fact that it's also in your artisan responses seems to point to a deeper problem you are unlikely to have caused just by writing views and controller methods. The quiz form uses Angular... Did you perhaps incorporate Angular and/or make other configuration changes to your project just before writing the quiz features? If so, I would be tempted to try rolling back and reapplying/resetting any such recent changes.